# Emulate windowing SQL function in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have the following query to retrieve the top 2 papers (in terms of the number of citations) of every proceeding for researchers:

```
MATCH (p:Paper)-[:SUBMITTED_TO]->(a:Proceeding),(p)-[:CITED_BY]->()
WITH p.paperTitle as Paper, size((p)-[:CITED_BY]->()) as numCitations, 
collect(distinct a.proceedingName) as Proceedings
UNWIND Proceedings AS Proceeding
WITH Paper, numCitations, Proceeding
ORDER BY Paper, numCitations, Proceeding
RETURN Paper, numCitations, collect(Proceeding) as Proceedings
ORDER BY Proceedings, numCitations DESC
```

The output I get from this is:

```
Paper      numCitations     Proceedings
Title1     4                Proc1
Title2     3                Proc1
Title3     2                Proc1
Title4     7                Proc2
Title5     5                Proc2
Title6     3                Proc2
Title7     8                Proc3
Title8     4                Proc3
Title9     2                Proc3
```

What I want to do now is to get only the top 2 of all the papers that appear for each proceeding (three for all of them), but if I use **LIMIT 2** at the end of the query, I only get the top 2 of everything (not for each proceeding):

```
Paper      numCitations     Proceedings
Title7     8                Proc3
Title4     7                Proc2
```

Note that Proc1 was completely discarded. This is not what I am looking for. Any ideas on how to do this in Neo4j?

Thanks!

Comment: What about sample test data? And an example of the desired result? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query I use in genealogy to pull out the two oldest children of a set of men (identified by their RN):

```
match (p:Person)<-[:father]-(c:Person) where p.RN in [5,7,27]
with p, c order by c.BD
with p.RN as RN,collect(c.fullname) as cC
return RN,cC[0..2]
```

By analogy, you can sort your data by the numCitations (rather than birth date) and then limit the result to 2.

Comment: Sorry, it did not work for me. The result is the same I am getting

Comment: give us a sample of an original dataset, preferably in a set of queries to create the nodes and edges. The data you provided above is a result and not the original.